# Group by dataframe using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, keyword

Lets say i have df like this

| ID | name_x | st | string |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | xx | us | Being unacquainted with the chief raccoon was harming his prospects for promotion |
| 2 | xy | us1 | The overpass went under the highway and into a secret world |
| 3 | xz | us | He was 100% into fasting with her until he understood that meant he couldn't eat |
| 4 | xu | us2 | Random words in front of other random words create a random sentence |
| 5 | xi | us1 | All you need to do is pick up the pen and begin |

Using python and pandas for column **st** I want count **name_x** values and then extract top 3 key words from string.

For example like this:

| st | name_x_count | top1_word | top2_word | top3_word |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| us | 2 | word1 | word2 | word3 |
| us1 | 2 | word1 | word2 | word3 |
| us2 | 1 | word1 | word2 | word3 |

Is there any way to solve this task?

Comment: What do you mean with "top 3 key words"? By frequency, TFIDF ? And in case of tie how would you decide?

Comment: Yes exactly...top 3 words by frequency. In case of tie i would decide by string lenght

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first groupby() to concatenate the strings as you show and then use collections `Counter` and then `most_common`. Finally assign it back to the dataframe. I am using `x.lower()` because otherwise "He" and "he" will be considered a different word (but you can always remove it if this is intended):

```
output = df.groupby('st').agg(
    name_x_count = pd.NamedAgg('name_x','count'),
    string = pd.NamedAgg('string',' '.join))
```

After grouping by we create the columns by using `collections.Counter()`:

```
output[['top1_word','top2_word','top3_word']] = output['string'].map(lambda x: [x[0] for x in collections.Counter(x.lower().split()).most_common(3)])
output = output.drop(columns='string')
```

Output:

```
     name_x_count top1_word top2_word top3_word
st                                             
us              2        he      with       was
us1             2       the       and  overpass
us2             1    random     words        in
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question...is there any way to group df by st, name_x_count  in order as i mention in main question?

Comment: Yes! I actually missed that originally, please check the edit now :)

Answer (score 1):

First, I added a space at the end of each string, as we will combine sentences while grouping. Then I consolidated the sentences after grouping by the st column.

```
df['string']=df['string'] + ' ' # we will use sum function. When combining sentences, there should be spaces in between.

dfx=df.groupby('st').agg({'st':'count','string':'sum'}) #groupby st and combine strings
```

Then list each word of the string expression, calculate their distribution and get the first 3 values.

```
from collections import Counter

mask=dfx['string'].apply(lambda x: list(dict(Counter(x.split()).most_common()[:3]).keys()))
print(mask)

'''
st  string
us  ['with', 'was', 'he']
us1 ['the', 'and', 'The']
us2 ['words', 'random', 'Random']


'''
```

Finally, add these first 3 words as new columns.

```
dfx[['top1_word','top2_word','top3_word']]=pd.DataFrame(mask.tolist(), index= mask.index)

dfx

st  name_x_count    top1_word   top2_word   top3_word
us  2               with        was         he
us1 2               the         and         The
us2 1               words       random      Random
```